# Search result on blank search query

Tags: search

When you click in search form and press 'Enter' or 'Submit' button, it returns all entries, that exist in database.

How could I display some message rather than all entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a conditional to check if your "search term" parameter has a value.

```
<h1>Search Results</h1>

{% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}

{% if query|length  %}

    {% set entries = craft.entries.search(query).order('score') %}

    {% if entries|length %}
        <p>{{ entries|length }} results:</p>

        <ul>
            {% for entry in entries %}
                <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>Your search for “{{ query }}” didn’t return any results.</p>
    {% endif %}


{% else %}
    <p>You forgot to enter a search term.</p>
{% endif %}
```

(This code is modified from the examples in the [Craft docs for "Search Form"](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/search-form))